# Type 'Player | undefined' is not assignable to type 'Player'. Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'Player'.ts(2322)

Tags: angular, typescript, socket.io

Am trying to maintain code , but my project doesn't compile I have this error from method where I can get player name from SocketID it tells me like title say that is undefined .
can you help me please maybe to modify this method to get it work?
thank you very much

```
getPlayerFromSocketID(socketId: string): Player {
    return this.players.find((p) => p.getSocketId() === socketId);
}
```

in others method like this on , I didn't get error

```
removePlayer(playerName: string): void {
    console.log('Removing player from playerManager : ' + playerName);
    const player = this.players.find((p) => p.getName() === playerName);

    if (player !== undefined) {
        this.players.splice(this.players.indexOf(player), 1);
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
getPlayerFromSocketID(socketId: string): Player {
```

You've said that you're going to return a Player, but the code actually can return undefined, so typescript is pointing out the mismatch. Since undefined is a possibility, update your return type:

```
getPlayerFromSocketID(socketId: string): Player | undefined {
```

Or alternatively, you could leave it off and then typescript will figure it out for you:

```
getPlayerFromSocketID(socketId: string) {
```